# Aggregate data frame on 2 columns, counting the leftover column by occurrence

Tags: r, aggregate, dplyr

I have a data frame:

```
    station  person_id   date
1    0037     103103  2015-02-02
2    0037     306558  2015-02-02
3    0037     306558  2015-02-04
4    0037     306558  2015-02-05
```

I need to aggregate the frame by station and date, so that every unique station/date (every row) in the result shows how many people fall on that row.

For example, the first 2 rows would collapse into a single row that shows 2 people for station 0037 and date 2015-02-02.

I tried,

```
result <- data_frame %>% group_by(station, week = week(date)) %>% summarise_each(funs(length), -date)
```

Comment: `summarize_each` is only necessary when you have multiple columns you want summarized, e.g., if you wanted the mean of four different columns at the station/date grouping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try:

```
group_by(df, station, date) %>% summarise(num_people = length(person_id))
Source: local data frame [3 x 3]
Groups: station [?]

  station       date num_people
    (int)     (fctr)      (int)
1      37 2015-02-02          2
2      37 2015-02-04          1
3      37 2015-02-05          1
```

Comment: Isn't this just `count(df, station, date)`? Or at least `group_by(df, station, date) %>% summarise(n())`?

Comment: Excellent. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In base R, you could use `aggregate`:

```
# sample dataset
set.seed(1234)
df <- data.frame(station=sample(1:3, 50, replace=T),
                 person_id=sample(30000:35000, 50, replace=T),
                 date=sample(seq(as.Date("2015-02-05"), as.Date("2015-02-12")
                                 by="day"), 50, replace=T))

# calculate number of people per station on a particular date
aggregate(cbind("passengerCount"=person_id) ~ station + date, data=df, FUN=length)
```

The `cbind` function is not necessary, but it lets you provide a variable name.

Answer (score 0):

With `data.table`, we convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table', grouped by 'station', 'date', we get the number of rows (`.N`).

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, .(num_people = .N), .(station, date)]
#   station       date num_people
#1:      37 2015-02-02          2
#2:      37 2015-02-04          1
#3:      37 2015-02-05          1
```